# why after adding normal texture dark pixel areas appear on mesh?

Tags: texture-painting, normal-map

i made a texture for normal map , without normal map mesh is very smooth
[image]

but after adding normal map dark pixel areas appear
[image]

i check shader settings in shader editor
[image]

color space is "Non Color"
and my normal texture is just a constant color
[image]

and also i check the normals directions
[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Have you checked if your model has [custom split normals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/structure.html#custom-split-normals)?

Comment: Or maybe share your file so we could take a look.